# How to get the right JSONPath?

Tags: json, xpath, jsonpath

I have the following JSON structure:

```
[{"Name":"Ab1","Price":"153"},{"Name":"Cd2","Price":"179"},...]
```

I want wo write a XPath command which gets the `Price` for the Element which `Name` is `Ab1`

I tried the following: `"//Name[Ab1]/Price"` 
But this is not working for me.

Comment: sorry for my ignorance, but isn't xpath for xml only?

Comment: What toolkit are you using to query xpath like expressions against a json structure?  There is JSONPath, https://code.google.com/p/jsonpath/, for example.  Is that what you are using?

Comment: I did not know JSONPath, but //Name[data(.)='Ab1']/Price Xpath should be correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JSONPath syntax is very different from XPath. It's just based on XPath's concept.

This should be the correct JSONPath in your case. Please give it a try:

```
$[?(@.Name == 'Ab1')].Price
```

Answer (score 0):

With DefiantJS (http://defianjs.com), you can query JSON structure using XPath expressions. DefiantJS extends the global object JSON with the method "search" and it returns matches as an array-like object.

Here is an example code;

```
    var data = [
       {
          "Name": "Ab1",
          "Price": "153"
       },
       {
          "Name": "Cd2",
          "Price": "179"
       }
    ],
    found = JSON.search(data, "//*[./Name='Ab1']/Price");

document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = found[0];
```

To see this code in action, check out this fiddle; http://jsfiddle.net/hbi99/a9uZ3/

For more useful XPath expressions, see the like XPath Evaluator here;
http://defiantjs.com/#xpath_evaluator